# Derivatives of trig functions

Tags: calculus

I am trying to figure out the derivative of $y= \frac{t\sin t}{1+t}$
I know the quotient rules are needed but I think what is confusing is some fairly simple math. Here is what I did.

(1+t)(tcost) - (tsint)(1) this could be wrong but I think it is correct. Anyways what I was confused on was multiplying t into tcost. I forget the rules but is tcost times t should be $t^2\cos$ or something close but I am not sure. Anyways I end up with $ \frac{t\cos t+t^2 \cos t - t \sin t}{(1+t)^2}$ but this is not correct.

Comment: Currently you have $1+\sec \theta$ at the bottom.  Is that intended?

Comment: I fixed it, that should be the correct problem now. I don't understand what $t\cos\,t\tan\frac{t}{2}$ is

Comment: You almost did it right. The "I think it is correct" part is not. You want $(1+t)$ times the *derivative* of $t\sin t$ minus $t\sin t$.  The derivative of $t\sin t$ is not $t\cos t$, it is $t\cos t +\sin t$ (product rule).

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to say, but is my derivative of tsint wrong? Thinking about it now it should be the derivative of tsint which would be sint(1) + cost(t) is that correct?

Comment: "but is my derivative of tsint wrong" - Yes, exactly. And $\sin t (1) + \cos t (t)$ is correct derivative of $t \sin t$.

Comment: I am still getting the wrong answer I think $(sintt+tcost) (1+t) + (tsint) is that right up to that point?

Comment: No, the quotient rule is $(u/v)'$ equals $u' v$ *minus* $u v'$. $u'v$ here is $(\sin t + t \cos t)(1+t)$. And $uv' = t \sin t \cdot 1 = t \sin t$. Both are correct. What's wrong is the sign. Can you fix it?

Comment: Oh sorry I had the correct sign in my work, I just typed the wrong sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product and quotient rules need to be used here.  For example, we can first use the product rule
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{t\sin(t)}{1+t}\right)
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{t}{1+t}\sin(t)\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{t}{1+t}\right)\sin(t)+\frac{t}{1+t}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\sin(t)\right)
\end{align}
$$
and then use the quotient rule for $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{t}{1+t}$. Alternatively, there is nothing wrong with using the quotient rule first and then using the product rule for $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(t\sin(t))$.